# Difference between spacy v3 en_core_web_trf pipeline and en_core_web_lg pipeline

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-transformers, spacy-3

I am doing some performance tests with spacy version 3 for right sizing my instances in production. I am observing the following

**Observation:**

| Model name | Time without NER | Time with NER | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| en_core_web_lg | 4.89 seconds | 21.9 seconds | NER adds 350% to the original time |
| en_core_web_trf | 43.64 seconds | 52.83 seconds | NER adds just 20% to the original time |

*Why is there no significant difference between the **with NER** and **without NER** scenarios in the case of the transformer model? Is NER just an incremental task after POS tagging in the case of en_core_web_trf?*

**Test environment:** GPU instance

**Test code:**

```
import spacy

assert(spacy.__version__ == '3.0.3')
spacy.require_gpu()
texts = load_sample_texts()  # loads 10,000 texts from a file
assert(len(texts) == 10000)

def get_execution_time(nlp, texts, N):
    return timeit.timeit(stmt="[nlp(text) for text in texts]", 
                           globals={'nlp': nlp, 'texts': texts}, number=N) / N


#  load models
nlp_lg_pos = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg', disable=['ner', 'parser'])
nlp_lg_all = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
nlp_trf_pos = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf', disable=['ner', 'parser'])
nlp_trf_all = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

#  get execution time
print(f'nlp_lg_pos = {get_execution_time(nlp_lg_pos, texts, N=1)}')
print(f'nlp_lg_all = {get_execution_time(nlp_lg_all, texts, N=1)}')
print(f'nlp_trf_pos = {get_execution_time(nlp_trf_pos, texts, N=1)}')
print(f'nlp_trf_all = {get_execution_time(nlp_trf_all, texts, N=1)}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert, but I think this may be due to the design of the pipelines.

## [Trained pipeline design](https://spacy.io/models#design)

The [docs](https://spacy.io/models#design-cnn) for the `sm/md/lg` models state:

> The `ner` component is independent with its own internal tok2vec layer.
> [image: sm/md/lg pipeline design]

And the [docs](https://spacy.io/models#design-trf) for the `trf` model states:

> In the transformer (`trf`) models, the `tagger`, `parser` and `ner` (if present) all listen to the `transformer` component.

## [Shared embedding layers](https://spacy.io/usage/embeddings-transformers#embedding-layers)

> Reusing the tok2vec layer between components can make your pipeline run a lot faster and result in much smaller models. However, it can make the pipeline less modular and make it more difficult to swap components or retrain parts of the pipeline.
> [image: shared vs independent]

| SHARED | INDEPENDENT |
| --- | --- |
| ✅ **smaller:** models only need to include a single copy of the embeddings | ❌ **larger:** models need to include the embeddings for each component |
| ✅ **faster:** embed the documents once for your whole pipeline | ❌ **slower:** rerun the embedding for each component |
| ❌ **less composable:** all components require the same embedding component in the pipeline | ✅ **modular:** components can be moved and swapped freely |

## Experiments

- **NOTE 1:** I'm using the [20 newsgroups text  dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/real_world.html#the-20-newsgroups-text-dataset) and I don't have a GPU so times may vary, but results point in the same general direction.
- **NOTE 2:** I am using:

  - `spacy` 3.5.4
  - `en_core_web_lg` 3.5.0
  - `en_core_web_trf` 3.5.0
  - `scikit-learn` 1.3.0
  - `Python` 3.11.4.

```py
"""Replicating code as much as possible."""

import timeit

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import spacy  # 3.5.4


# spacy.require_gpu()  # I don't have a GPU available
bunch = fetch_20newsgroups(random_state=0)
texts = bunch.data

def get_execution_time(nlp, texts, N):
    return timeit.timeit(
        stmt="[nlp(text) for text in texts]",
        globals={'nlp': nlp, 'texts': texts},
        number=N
    ) / N

#  load models
nlp_lg_pos = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg', disable=['ner', 'parser'])
nlp_lg_all = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
nlp_trf_pos = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf', disable=['ner', 'parser'])
nlp_trf_all = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

#  get execution time
print(f'nlp_lg_pos = {get_execution_time(nlp_lg_pos, texts, N=1)}')
print(f'nlp_lg_all = {get_execution_time(nlp_lg_all, texts, N=1)}')
print(f'nlp_trf_pos = {get_execution_time(nlp_trf_pos, texts, N=1)}')
print(f'nlp_trf_all = {get_execution_time(nlp_trf_all, texts, N=1)}')
```

| Model name | Time without NER or Parser | Time with NER and Parser | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `en_core_web_lg` | 8.48 seconds | 13.98 seconds | NER and Parser add 65% to original time |
| `en_core_web_trf` | 387.67 seconds | 382.84 seconds | NER and Parser reduce time by 1% (negligible) |

It is difficult to modify an existing component and have it listen to the shared `tok2vec` or `transformer` layer without retraining. So instead I will [replace](https://spacy.io/api/language#replace_listeners) the `en_core_web_trf` `ner` and `parser` component listeners with their own copies of the transformer layer. If the documentation is correct, this should cause the "Time with (Independent) NER and (Independent) Parser" results to be ***much*** slower than either of the previous `en_core_web_trf` results.

```py
nlp_trf_all_independent = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

# make `ner` and `parser` components independent
nlp_trf_all_independent.replace_listeners("transformer", "ner", ["model.tok2vec"])
nlp_trf_all_independent.replace_listeners("transformer", "parser", ["model.tok2vec"])

print(f'nlp_trf_all_independent = {get_execution_time(nlp_trf_all_independent, texts, N=1)}')
```

| Model name | Time without NER or Parser | Time with (Independent) NER and (Independent) Parser | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `en_core_web_trf` | 387.67 seconds | 1125.31 seconds | (Independent) NER and (Independent) Parser add 190% to the original time |

As you can see, making components independent, i.e. not sharing/listening to `tok2vec`/`transformer` layers, results in a slower (but more modular) pipeline. I believe this is the reason that the `en_core_web_lg` model is noticeably slower when you add the `ner` component as it is independent by default.